# Expansion of inverse of sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two invertible Hermitian pd matrices $A$ and $B$ and a positive real number $t$. What is,
$$(A+tB)^{-1}=?$$
in terms of powers of $A$, $B$, and $t$.

Comment: There isn't a nice expansion unless $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ don't commute. What is the not-nice expansion? That might be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following identity:

$$(A + tB)^{-1} = (A(I + tA^{-1}B))^{-1} = (I + t A^{-1}B)^{-1} A^{-1}$$

Assuming that $t$ is sufficiently small, you can now apply the binomial series:
$$(I + tX)^{-1} = \sum \limits_{i = 0}^\infty (-tX)^{i}$$

Comment: How small $t$ should be here?

Comment: @ItIsComplicated The eigenvalues of $tX$ should all have an absolute value of less than 1. Essentially the identity holds as long as the term on the right is well-defined. So it suffices that there is a submultiplicative Matrix-norm so that $\|tX\| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The best we can do is as follows.  Let $M$ denote any matrix for which $A^{-1} = M^*M$.  We can then write
$$
(A + tB)^{-1} = (M^{-*}[I + t(M^*BM)]M^{-1})^{-1} = 
M(I + t(M^*BM))^{-1}M^*
$$
Now, letting $C = M^*BM$, we compute
$$
(I + tC)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kt^kC^k
$$
whenever $t \leq \|C\|$.

Comment: Notably, $C$ here is necessarily positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good way to do this in general. If the sum converges, which it likely won't, you can do
$$(1+tA^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-tA^{-1}B)^n)A^{-1}$$

Comment: $A^{-1}$ should be multiplied from the right, as taking the inverse switches the order of multiplication.

Comment: @Dom You're right, thanks.